# Firefox Aborted Request issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, firefox, browser

I am using Angularjs to load content in my application, further Angularjs is calling Rest Services to get the data. I am refreshing page(F5) when my Rest requests are in progress and waiting for Server Response, status in the the console is displaying as Aborted and application getting redirected to the domain. for e.g. https://example.com/api/rest/data refreshing page displaying the url in firebug console as GET example.com and my nginx configuration redirecting me to login page. Why i am getting redirected to domain on request abort? Is this is a Firefox Feature/Issue?

Comment: Aborting issue happens when one request is in progress and you refresh page then it aborts first requests which are not completed or not having status 200.

Comment: I am not facing this issue with any other browser this is specific to Firefox. Does that mean firefox forwarding me to domain itself?